# Python/lxml is eating too much memory

Tags: python, optimization, memory-leaks, lxml

The program is quite simple, recursively descend to directories and extract an element. The directories are 1k with about 200 files of 0.5m.
I see that it consumes about 2.5g of memory after some time, it's completely unacceptable, the script's not alone to eat up everything. I cannot understand why it doesn't release the memory. Explicit del doesn't help.
Are there any techniques to consider?

```
from lxml import etree
import os

res=set()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
    for i in files:
        tree = etree.parse(os.path.join(root,i), parser)
        for i in tree.xpath("//a[@class='ctitle']/@href"):
            res.add(i)
        del tree
```

Comment: What type is `i`? What are you going to do with `res`?

Comment: Oh, well, different i here:) No big problem, but not elegant. Outer i is string, inner i is lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult which I believe is converted to a string easily. Could the memory be cluttered with those elements, you mean? I don't delete them, yes. I'll check. For now I store the res (many duplicates, so it's about 100 results per directory).

Comment: How are you measuring memory consumption?

Comment: @LukasGraf: With top. This process constantly increases its memory footprint… And yes, organoleptically too, when everything else is being swapped out:)

Comment: So what are you looking at? VSZ (virtual set size) or RSS (resident set size) (resp VIRT/RES in top)? If it's just VSZ that's high, that isn't necessarily an issue.

Comment: @LukasGraf: After 10 directories: KiB Mem:   4049356 total,  4018984 used,    30372 free,     2488 buffers
KiB Swap: 12582904 total,  1570596 used, 11012308 free.    52256 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                   
14211 pooh      20   0 1220464 1.083g   3104 R  90.8 28.1   1:22.79 python3.4

Comment: The `lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult` objects themselves are probably not using that much memory, but since you can do `.getparent()` on them, they keep a reference to the tree, which means the tree can't be garbage collected by Python. So from what I see, turning them into strings before adding them to your set *should* help the garbage collector do its job.

Comment: @Pooh: this is a known and documented behaviour cf http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm and the linked post.

Comment: Err actually I failed to spot the problem mentionned by Lukas Graf - reopening the question since it might well have something to do with this issue too.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers still a good point, I was thinking about that behavior too, but I'm not sure it necessarily applies in this case - OP shouldn't have huge amounts of values of primitive types in memory *at the same time*. Hard to say for sure though.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Thank you, it solved the issue. Stable at 0.7%. So well, if you need upvote, you can answer the question:)

Comment: Great. Memory optimization is rarely that easy, glad it worked ;-)

Comment: @LukasGraf: I'm very new to python, so there's still much to learn in regard of differences between pythonic way and my inbred C approach:)

Comment: @LukasGraf: Argh! I was reloading the page but for some reason Peter's answer was not displayed:( Now there was, and was yours, I felt as I ought to give precedence to him as he was the first to react and bring the issue of storing elements in a list into consideration (which you have elaborated). And now I see that you have removed the answer. Again I'm disenchanted by SO I spent once too much time on.

Comment: @Pooh he deleted it intermittently, undeleted and edited it. It's fine, his post answers the issue just as well, so I removed mine.

Comment: @LukasGraf I didn't mean to deceive, that's just how it came about (c: I probably should have started a new answer and didn't think of the consequences. Pooh, please don't be disenchanted. This is a great site, with some really helpful, knowledgeable, and genuinely nice people. I wouldn't want my answering your question to make you disenchanted. What would make you happier? I answer to be helpful and to make people happy, not for upvotes (although they make me feel appreciated, that's not what drives me).

Comment: @PeterWood: Oh, thank you for replying:) No, SO won't make me any happy, people are good, but having no control over the question (for example I asked something on SO and it was transferred to unix) is what made me to stop using it. So now I use it only when I'm totally stuck. Now I was disenchanted by the fact that I was reloading the page and your answer didn't show up. Now I see it wasn't a bug of SO, and it's good:)

Comment: @PeterWood no worries, I figured as much. It's all good ;-)

Comment: @LukasGraf thank you thank you thank you :-) saved my day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're keeping references to an element from the tree, an `_ElementUnicodeResult`. The element keeps references to its parent. This prevents the whole tree from being garbage collected.

Try converting the element to a string and store that:

```
from lxml import etree
import os

titles = set()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
    for filename in files:
        tree = etree.parse(os.path.join(root, filename), parser)
        for title in tree.xpath("//a[@class='ctitle']/@href"):
            titles.add(str(title))
```